# Outer Join 3 Tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. `Table1` belongs to `Table2`, and `Table2` belongs to `Table3`.

I want to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that includes all of the fields from all 3 tables, including nulls (outer joining to get all of Table1), with a WHERE clause on Table1 and an order by a column in Table3.

What I want in SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.id = Table1.table2_id
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.id = Table2.table3_id
WHERE Table1.column1 = "example"
ORDER BY Table3.table3_column
```

However, I have been trying for hours now to do this in rails and getting nowhere. Is it possible?

```
@records = Table1.joins(:table2).joins(:table3).where(:column1 => "example").order("table3_column")
```

(For example), gets me nowhere because it is looking for an association between Table1 and Table3, which doesn't exist other than through Table2. I need to join once, then join on top of that. Not to mention that is an inner join. I've tried of the form:

```
@records = Table1.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.id = Table1.table2_id LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.id = Table2.table3_id")
```

But I get nil from that.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Just use find_by_sql?

Answer (score 0):

Try `find_by_sql`

```
Table1.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.id = Table1.table2_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.id = Table2.table3_id
WHERE Table1.column1 = "example"
ORDER BY Table3.table3_column")
```

refer [find by sql](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding_by_sql)